# Spring Boot custom parameter resolver with WebFlux

Tags: spring-boot, rest

I have a student class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Student {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private int age;
}
```

and a custom annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.PARAMETER)
public @interface JsonBody {
    String encoding() default "utf-8";
}
```

My controller looks like

```
@GetMapping("/student")
public String student(@JsonBody Student student) {
    return student.toString();
}
```

I also registered a custom resolver

```
public class StudentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

@Override
public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
    return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonBody.class) != null;
}

@Override
public Object resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, ModelAndViewContainer modelAndViewContainer, NativeWebRequest nativeWebRequest, WebDataBinderFactory webDataBinderFactory) throws Exception {
    JsonBody annotation = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonBody.class);
    ServletRequest servletRequest = nativeWebRequest.getNativeRequest(ServletRequest.class);
    String request = StreamUtils.copyToString(servletRequest.getInputStream(), Charset.forName(annotation.encoding()));
    System.out.println(request);
    return new Student("Indiana", "Jones", 50);
}
```

When calling the api with

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/student' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
"firstName": "John",
"lastName": "Doe",
"age": "20"
}'
```

I have the right answer

```
Student(firstName=Indiana, lastName=Jones, age=50)
```

And I can see ine the log the expected json from resquest

```
{
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "age": "20"
}
```

Now I want to do the same thing with `webflux`

My resolver becomes

```
public class StudentResolver implements HandlerMethodArgumentResolver {

    @Override
    public boolean supportsParameter(MethodParameter methodParameter) {
        return methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonBody.class) != null;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Object> resolveArgument(MethodParameter methodParameter, BindingContext bindingContext, ServerWebExchange serverWebExchange) {
        JsonBody annotation = methodParameter.getParameterAnnotation(JsonBody.class);
    
        ServerHttpRequest serverHttpRequest = serverWebExchange.getRequest();
        Flux<DataBuffer> dataBufferFlux = serverHttpRequest.getBody();
        dataBufferFlux
            .log()
            .subscribe(dataBuffer -> System.out.println(dataBuffer));

    return Mono.just(new Student("Indiana", "Jones", 50));
}
```

It is also giving the right answer.

But I don't know what to do in the `resolveArgument` method.

Comment: Why would you need a dedicated resolver for that? That is supported out-of-the-box (the same for making JSON out of a student).

Comment: My problem is not why but how. :-)  I edited my question for webflux.

Comment: Still feels like you are replacing something which works out-of-the-box with a halfarsed version you build yourself. But if you really must or want to you can use the `ServerWebExchange` to get the body and read it to use it.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried like in my edited question.  But I its displaying nothing.  I only see onSubscribe(FluxMap.MapSubscriber) and request(unbounded)